# rospack cannot find package every-time terminal restarted

Tags: ros, turtlebot, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two packages one name test_package (built first) and one name cylinder(later).
I found that every time I start a new terminal or restart the terminal, I have to source the setup.bash again for cylinder package otherwise it is not found.  For every terminal, I need to source before running rosrun cylinder xxx.
The test_package worked fine.
I wonder if is there a solution, shall I just try rebuild this package again, I don't know whether rebuilding work or not though... Has anyone else experienced this before?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306409/rospack-cannot-find-package-every-time-terminal-restarted/) by [lenkazuma](https://answers.ros.org/users/38141/lenkazuma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-10-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is exactly what we'd expect.

If you want the cylinder package to always be available you'll need to add a line into your `.bashrc` file to source it for you. `.bashrc` is located in your home folder and you'll want to add a line like the one below but update the path to match where your cylinder package is:

```
source /home/your_user/cylinder_workspace/devel/setup.bash
```

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2